# Rails 5 - Creating nested resource through UJS / remote: true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a working implementation where I have a parent resource called `MultipleChoiceQuestion` that a `User` can have many of.

`MultipleChoiceQuestion` has several attributes, starting with `question` (which is the question itself) along with its answer choice attributes which are `answer_one`, `answer_two`, `answer_three`, `answer_four`, and `answer_five` along with `answer_correct`

I need to be able to display the question along with all of the answer choices, and let users select an answer, persist it, and allow them to see which questions they answered right or wrong.

I'm thinking that a new model must be made such as `UserAnswer`, but I'm not sure what the attributes of it should be, considering it will belong to `MultipleChoiceQuestion` - and how to pass the parameters to this new model is what i'm stuck on.

Here's the relevant code:

**MultipleChoiceQuestions controller**

```
  def tagged
    @mcqs = MultipleChoiceQuestion.with_tag(params[:tag]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
    authorize @mcqs
  end

def verify_user_selected_answer
    @multiple_choice_question = MultipleChoiceQuestion.find(params[:question])
    @selected_answer = params[:answer]
    @user_id_who_selceted = params[:current_user]


    if @selected_answer.downcase == @multiple_choice_question.answer_correct.downcase
      @result = "Correct answer!"
    else
      @result = "Wrong answer!"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { result: @result } }
    end
  end
```

tagged.html.erb

```
  <% @mcqs.each do |mcq| %>
<% mcq.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <%= link_to answer, "javascript:void(0);", class: "answer" %>

    </div>

  <% end %>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
var current_answer = $(this);
var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

$.ajax({
url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
success: function(response){
$("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
}
});
});
});

</script>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  post '/verify_user_selected_answer', to: "multiple_choice_questions#verify_user_selected_answer"
```

in the rails console, the data parameters are being passed and this is the proof

```
Started POST "/verify_user_selected_answer" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-19 16:15:16 +0500
Processing by MultipleChoiceQuestionsController#verify_user_selected_answer as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "question"=>"77", "answer"=>"answer four"}
```

it has the user id who attempted it, the question id, and what answer was selected.
i need to persist these attempts in a separate model it seems like, but it has to be done through Ajax.

**Basically, to be able to see how many people attempted any single question, who selected what choice, and the user themselves should be able to see which ones they got right and wrong over time is what i'm asking help for** - thank you!!

Edit:

MultipleChoiceQuestion.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: multiple_choice_questions
#
#  id                                         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  question                                   :text
#  answer_one                                 :text
#  answer_two                                 :text
#  answer_three                               :text
#  answer_four                                :text
#  answer_correct                             :text
#  answer_explanation                         :text
#  published                                  :boolean
#  flagged                                    :boolean
#  user_id                                    :bigint(8)
#  created_at                                 :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                                 :datetime         not null
#  slug                                       :string           not null


class MultipleChoiceQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :user, presence: true

  belongs_to :multiple_choice_question_classification, optional: true

  has_many :flags, dependent: :destroy

  acts_as_taggable

  # activity feed
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new { |controller, model| controller.current_user ? controller.current_user : nil }

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :question, use: %i(slugged history finders)

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id? #will change the slug if the name changed
    question_changed?
  end

  def answers
    [answer_one, answer_two,
    answer_three, answer_four,
    answer_correct].shuffle
  end


end
```

**User.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  first_name             :string
#  last_name              :string
#  school_name            :string
#  graduation_year        :string
#  current_sign_in_token  :string
#  admin                  :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  superadmin             :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  verified               :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  premiumuser            :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  banneduser             :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  user_role              :boolean          default(TRUE)
#  username               :string           default(""), not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :multiple_choice_questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :verbal_questions

  has_many :flags
  has_many :saved_items

  has_many :reviews



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with a classic [`has_many, <> :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. The steps should include the below

**Steps:**

1) Generate a new model, say `UserAnswer` with the below command

```
rails g generate model UserAnswer user_id:integer multiple_choice_question_id:integer selected_answer:text is_correct_answer:boolean
```

and do `rake db:migrate` to add the table in the DB.

2) Remove the `user_id` column in `multiple_choice_questions` table. You don't require it now

3) Alter the associations to include the new model

```
#multiple_choice_question.rb
has_many :user_answers
has_many :users, through: :user_answers

#user.rb
has_many :user_answers
has_many :multiple_choice_questions, through: :user_answers

#user_answer.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :multiple_choice_question
```

4) Add the creation of entries for `user_answers` in the `verify_user_selected_answer` method like below

```
def verify_user_selected_answer
  @multiple_choice_question = MultipleChoiceQuestion.find(params[:question])
  @selected_answer = params[:answer]
  @user_id_who_selceted = User.find(params[:user_id]) #look for the change here

  if @selected_answer.downcase == @multiple_choice_question.answer_correct.downcase
    UserAnswer.create(multiple_choice_question_id: @multiple_choice_question.id, user_id: @user_id_who_selceted.id, selected_answer: @selected_answer, is_correct_answer: true)
    @result = "Correct answer!"
  else
    UserAnswer.create(multiple_choice_question_id: @multiple_choice_question.id, user_id: @user_id_who_selceted.id, selected_answer: @selected_answer, is_correct_answer: false)
    @result = "Wrong answer!"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { result: @result } }
  end
end
```

This will allow you to add new entries to the `user_answers` upon every time when a user picks an answer for a question.

Comment: How would I see who made the MultipleChoiceQuestion in the first place then?

Comment: @mazing Upon that action performed by an user an entry will be stored in `user_answers` table. This will help you to do `@user_id_who_selceted.multiple_choice_questions` which will give that particular users `MultipleChoiceQuestion` instances